# Python: Correct use of Click with __main__ and __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, python-click

I have been playing around with the [Click package](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) and I can't get the following snippit of code to work properly.

```
import numpy as np
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--get_print', default = True)

class CustomClass():

     def __init__(s, get_print):

        s.data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
        s.get_print = get_print

        if s.get_print:
            print("get_print =", s.get_print)

     def print_mean(s):

        print("Printing mean:")

        mean_ = np.mean(s.data)

        if s.get_print:

            print(mean_)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomClass().print_mean()
```

It seems that the `print_mean` function never gets called. If I comment out the @Click decorator, and manually set `get_print=True`, the `print_mean` method gets called just fine.

My suspicion is that @Click somehow sets `__main__` and so when I do `if __name__ == '__main__'` it just calls Click again - but perhaps I'm wrong?

In either case, what is the *correct* way of using Click, when you want the `__init__` method to inherit all the options, and `if __name__ == '__main__'`to actually be able to call functions inside the class, where the `__init__` is defined?

Comment: you are decorating a class with `@click.command()`; the only examples i found decorate functions... (but maybe i missed something in the doc...)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist is right.  You need to decorate a function.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist & @Stephen Rauch, yes, usually you decorate a function with Click, but I am interested in how `__init__` can inherit commands from click, without "taking over" the use of `__main__`. How else would you use Click together with classes?

Comment: why do you insist of having `click` interact directly with your class and not via a function as in all the examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just to illustrate what I mean in my comments. Decorate a function with the `click` functions and have that function instantiate your class and execute whatever member function you need. This is what the click docs suggests:

```
import numpy as np
import click

class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, get_print):
        self.data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
        self.get_print = get_print

        if self.get_print:
            print("get_print =", self.get_print)

    def print_mean(self):
        print("Printing mean:")
        mean_ = np.mean(self.data)
        if self.get_print:
            print(mean_)

@click.command()
@click.option('--get_print', default=True)
def cli(get_print):
    cc = CustomClass(get_print)
    cc.print_mean()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

...and you probably want `get_print` to be a flag with default `False`:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--get_print', default=False, is_flag=True, required=False)
def cli(get_print):
    cc = CustomClass(get_print)
    cc.print_mean()
```

Comment: Ah. I get your comments now. I thought you referred to decorating the function *inside* the class with Click, which made no sense to me. I guess the above works. Thanks!